# What do you call the support post for a pothos?

Tags: vines, trellis

I'm trying to buy a post for a potted pothos like I've seen many times, but I don't know what they're called. None of my searches have had any results.

The type I'm referring to is generally square in cross section and seems to be made of loosely compressed fibers of some sort, possibly even grape vines.

Answer (score 7):

I think you are looking for a moss pole. They come in round and square shapes. [Google Images Moss Pole](https://www.google.com/search?q=moss%20pole&espv=2&biw=1521&bih=904&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjG7raa18XKAhVHyYMKHSLRDSUQsAQIGw#imgrc=_).

Comment: What I see used by growers is dry and fibrous. It looks like osmunda fibre only of an unusually large size

Comment: @kevinsky: What I'm looking for is coarser, dry and fibrous, as you say, than the moss poles appear to be. Based on Debbie's suggestion, I found that "tree fern totem" may be what I'm looking for and posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Searching on Amazon for "moss pole" based on Debbie M's suggestion, I found "tree fern totem" which seemed to be closer to what I'm looking for. Searching for the latter on Google, I found that they are commonly used for orchids and a couple of references to use with pothos.